# getting lines between two patterns

Tags: bash, shell, unix

### DATA IN FILE

SQL>DELETE *FROM ABC;
RAM
SQL>DELETE *FROM LMN;
RAJ

I want to extract the data in reverse order between **RAJ** AND THE FIRST PATTERN **SQL>** FOUND
Output Required:
SQL>DELETE *FROM LMN;
RAJ

Comment: And how did you try to achieve that? You are aware that StackOverflow is meant to help with programming problems, not for being a free code writing service, are you?

Answer (score 0):

```
tac file.txt|sed -n '/^RAJ/,/^SQL>/p'|tac
```

---

1. **tac:** cat file in reverse order
2. **sed:** print only line between RAJ and SQL>

---

Example `file.txt`

```
SQL>DELETE *FROM ABC;
RAM
SQL>DELETE *FROM LMN;
RAJ
SQL>DELETE *FROM CDE;
RAM
SQL>DELETE *FROM XYZ;
RAJ
```

Results:

```
SQL>DELETE *FROM LMN;
RAJ
SQL>DELETE *FROM XYZ;
RAJ
```